# How to auto format Javascript in GWT's native methods with eclispe

Tags: javascript, eclipse, gwt, code-formatting

After reinitialize my GWT project the auto formatting for native JavaScript methodes doesn't work anymore, how can I enable it again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if you are opening source files with `GWT Java Editor` instead of normal `Java Editor`.

Just right click on the java file, select `Open With`, and `GWT Java Editor` should be there.